# Currency Pipe in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe, currency

Hi I want to display price in USD format i.e, for commas 
for eg. $123,456
But if use currency pipe in angular 2 with USD ,i have to have either $ or USD
Is it possible that I can display only number without USD and $?

My code is {{123456 | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}

making it to false giving me error.

I am getting display as $123,456 or USD123,456.
BUT i want it as 123,456.

Comment: is it possible to format only number? Like 1,000

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe you could just use the [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html). It seems to cover your needs.

```
{{123456 | number:'.2-2'}} would become 123,456.00
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

just use below kendo numeric textbox th currency symbol coming automatically

```
 <kendo-numerictextbox
            [format]="'c'" [Spinners]="false"
            [value]="value"
        ></kendo-numerictextbox>
```

Answer (score -7):

[ngModel]="123456 |  currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'"

the above code useful for you