# Formatting a number to have commas at every 1000 factor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipes-filters

I need to format a number like `1234567` as `1,234,567` but don't know how to do this. I tried using currency pipe of TypeScript but that gives USD or $ in front of the number. I want to remove that and format the number in this way `1,234,567`. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused: if you don't want a currency prefix, why are you using the currency pipe? Is your real question "how do I format a number so that it has commas for every factor of one thousand"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currency Pipe in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392293/currency-pipe-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes i just need to format a number in this way 1,234,567 for 1234567. so, tried using currency pipe as it formatting the number in the same way i want but with usd prefixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: That was also a hint for you to search for that instead - JavaScript has this built in already, you don't need angular or typescript to do this, so if you searched for "adding commas to number in javascript" you would have absolutely found the answer to this (using JS's `toLocaleString()`)

Comment: In addition to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans suggestion: `(1234567).toLocaleString('en-US')`.

Comment: @all Got this fixed by just using number pipe of angular core instead of currency pipe and making changes to it. Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: It would be good to mark the answer accepted if you've used the solution provided by it ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting JavaScript number with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801564/formatting-javascript-number-with-commas)

Answer (score 68):

Just use the [number](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html) (decimal) pipe instead.

To give an example:

```
{{ '1234567' | number:'1.0':'en-US' }}
```

will produce output `1,234,567`.

If you do not change the default locale (by calling `registerLocaleData()` or providing [LOCALE_ID](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID)), then simple `{{'1234567' | number}}` will work as well.

Comment: or even simpler, `(123456789).toLocaleString()`, because JavaScript has this built in =)

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but usage examples would be good to make this more useful than a link-only answer.

Comment: @Aurora0001, example added. I haven't expected this question to get such engagement :)

Comment: @Mike, that's a very limited and unstable solution. For me `(1234567).toLocaleString()` produces `1 234 567`. Even if the result was  correct, I wouldn't use it in a serious project when better way is available.

Comment: @DanielKucal remember to add the local itself. `(1234567).toLocaleString("en")` if you need commas. With explicit locale, this *is* the most correct solution

Comment: This will produce a decimal `1,234,567.00`!!

Comment: In Angular 15+ import `DecimalPipe` from `@angular/common`

Answer (score 17):

The last answer will produce 1,234,567.00

Note the 2 decimals.

Use the following Pipe:

> {{ element.total | number: '2.'}}

In order to produce **1,234,567**

Comment: This produces single digit numbers as 01, 02, 03, etc. To just add commas, you can just use `{{ element.total | number }}`.

Comment: Provide a link in the comment instead of copying pasting the same answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364297/894532

Comment: What can we do in the Component file to modify data if i don't have the option to add pipe in template?

Comment: use these (taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_number_tofixed.htm):

num3.toFixed() is 177 
num3.toFixed(2) is 177.23 
num3.toFixed(6) is 177.234000

Answer (score 8):

Per the official Angular documentation for the [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe), which is defined with the structure `{{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}`, I was able achieve the desired number formatting by using:

```
{{ myValue | number:'':'en' }}
```

The empty string (`''`) causes the pipe to uses the default `digitsInfo` values for `minIntegerDigits` (1), `minFractionDigits` (0), and `maxFractionDigits` (3).

The locale being set to `en` causes the value to be displayed with commas marking the thousands, millions, etc. positions.

Comment: piggybacking on this `{{ myVAlue | number }}` also appears to work since the default locale is en-us.