# How to enter/show values with 'thousands' commas using an input type=number inside a mat-form-field inside an Angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

Summary Question:

(question only applies to input type='number')

*How to input/show values with 'thousands' commas (eg, 2,333,444) using an formcontrol of input of type=number inside a mat-form-field which resides within an Angular reactive form?*

Consider a reactive angular form:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="number' formcontrolname="myInput" matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

The form data model item for 'myInput' is bound to a number and cannot change. All is well when entering and displaying numbers (eg:2333444) **AND calculating other numbers based on it.**

Now, I'd like to display comma separated numbers in that input type=number field at every thousands (eg: 2,333,444).

I have a couple of elaborate tricks that would do this like creating a custom form field control ([see](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control)).

I understand the conflict between the input type=number, the collateral calculations AND requiring the text entry act like string/text with the commas--which is much better with input type="text". It is what it is.

Note 1: The input=number should show commas on initial load

Note 2: The input=number should automatically add commas on user input.

But is there a simpler way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify thousand separator for number pipe in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672225/how-to-specify-thousand-separator-for-number-pipe-in-angular-4)

Comment: Using Input number type is not possible to achieve this. IF you use input type text, it will be achievable.

Comment: @stavm not exactly.