# Currency Pipe CLP with cents, Angular 11

Tags: angular

hello guys i need tranform this value 23,769.05 to 23.769,05

in angular 11, searching I found this pipe but it has not worked for me:

[image]

[image]

please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify locale thousand separator for number pipe in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672225/how-to-specify-locale-thousand-separator-for-number-pipe-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to looks line an `en-ES` currency format.
I suggest to have a look on the [Number.toLocaleString() documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring_number.asp)

You can try something like:

```js
transform(value: number): string {
   return (value || 0).toLocaleString('es-ES');
}
```

Please avoid pasting code images, just use the markdown editor for your code. It's clearly better for helping.